# mongoose.js: finding data entries by day

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose this is your model:

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date
});
```

I would like to throw in a date (as simple as like '24-12-2012') and then retrieve every event that started or proceeded at that single day.

How do you do that?

Comment: See the Cookbook article on that subject: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

First read up on mongo query syntax for dates, here is a how-to for date ranges: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Then translate that mongo syntax into mongoose.

```
Event.where('startDate').lte(yourDate).exec(callback); //should do the trick
```

Now you just need to parse date strings to javascript dates. There are some cool libraries to do that, I believe that [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) won't have a problem with that date string.

Oh, I forgot the last bit of magic: Put that query into a [static method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/methods-statics.html) attached to your Event model, so from now on you can just call

```
Event.earlierThan(yourDate, callback); //Where your custom static is called 'earlierThan'.
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights. As far as I understand your code you will retrieve every event that started before a given date. So if I want to get everything at single day should I do a .gte("24-12-2012 00:00").lte("24-12-2012 23:59")? Also what about events that started the day before but ended on that day?

Comment: Hey there. Correct, yes and for the last case: just use `...where('endDate).lte(yourDate)`. :)

Comment: One correction for your comment above: `lte` and `gte` probably won't work with strings such as your `"24-12-2012 00:00"`, make sure you parse them into Javascript dates first!